# Servicestack Authentication IsAuthenticated always false

Tags: redis, servicestack

Hi am trying to use OAuth authentication provided by servicestack

```
plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]     {
new BasicAuthProvider(), new LinkedInOAuth2Provider(new AppSettings()),
new GoogleOAuth2Provider(new AppSettings()) }));

        //Use Redis Repo
        var userRepository = new RedisAuthRepository(redisClientsManager);
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);
        //Register Users with redis
        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

After Successful authentication by Google/LinkedIn the redis AuthRepo contains this,  We can see that isAuthenticated is False even after Successful authentication.

[image: We can see that isAuthenticated is False]

Could anyone let me know more about OAuth, Because there are many Secrets of it when comes to Mobile.

Eg: What Redirect Uri should i give in LinkedIn Console..! if i use OAuth for Mobiles ..? And how can i refresh session on each App StartUp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot does not show an authenticated User Session, which would have `IsAuthenticated = true` and include OAuth details returned by each OAuth provider in `ProviderOAuthAccess` collection.

#### ServiceStack OAuth Live Demos

See the [httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net](https://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net/) for an example of a working Live Demo that uses Google and LinkedIn OAuth2. The [HttpBenchmarks Github Repo](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#authentication) includes a step-by-step Guide explaining how to Configure OAuth in ServiceStack, including an example of a App Settings configuration and how to configure Glimpse for inspecting DotNetOpenAuth errors.

The [mvc.servicestack.net](http://mvc.servicestack.net/) Live Demo is another example that contains a working configuration using a number of Auth Providers.

#### Use AppHost AppSettings

When registering the OAuth Provider you should use the AppHost's `AppSettings` instead of injecting a `new AppSettings()` that way all Auth Providers will use the same configured [AppSettings for your AppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AppSettings#first-class-appsettings), e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new BasicAuthProvider(), 
        new LinkedInOAuth2Provider(base.AppSettings),
        new GoogleOAuth2Provider(base.AppSettings) 
    }));
```

Comment: Am Tying to use base.AppSettings but , am getting AppHostBase doest contain definition for AppSettings. Am not sure if am missing something here.

Comment: @TechCruize [AppSettings does exist on AppHostBase](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/bb49ddc3547b1dc94d3fad5c14686dbec0fb5f96/src/Chat/Global.asax.cs#L39-L45), so you do have something wrong, either you have a typo, are not in AppHost or are not using a recent version of ServiceStack.